# AWS EC2 ERROR: -bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm getting following error while doing tab. And unable to change the files, can open the files but not able to save the files. It looks like the server is working fine and long scripts are continuously executing and never ending.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-49-89:~$ cat /etc/issue.net
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

ubuntu@ip-172-31-49-89:~$ uname -a    
Linux ip-172-31-49-89 3.13.0-74-generic #118-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:52:10 
UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ubuntu@ip-172-31-49-89:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  376K   99M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       50G   47G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user

ubuntu@ip-172-31-49-89:~$ df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            125803    387  125416    1% /dev
tmpfs           127040    315  126725    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     3276800 134435 3142365    5% /
none            127040      2  127038    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            127040      1  127039    1% /run/lock
none            127040      1  127039    1% /run/shm
none            127040      2  127038    1% /run/user

ubuntu@ip-172-31-49-89:~$ cd new
-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

What should I do now? I just deleted my unnecessary founders and files. Still the same error after some time.

I tried solving this issue and my tmp and log files are smaller:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-49-89:~$ du -sh /tmp
1.3M    /tmp
ubuntu@ip-172-31-49-89:~$ du -sh /var/log
6.2M    /var/log
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need help with...? Your disk is full, so either delete some stuff or get a bigger one

Comment: Yes, I Know my disk is full. The files and folders what I created are needed. And those are not that big in size. Everything less than 1GB. I am not knowing where the disk is using. And now it is working, I haven't done anything. How do I track this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you said it yourself: you disk is full:

```
/dev/xvda1 50G 47G 0 100% /
```

Start investigating where you disk space is gone from the root folder:

```
du -hs /* | sort -h
```

That should give a pretty good idea what's occupying most of the disk drive.

Comment: Yes, I knew it, my disk is full and I am not knowing where it is using and what should i do. How do i find where the disk is using, I tried to open /dev/xvda1 everything empty. I am not knowing what is happening. I haven't done anything now it is working fine. Now the disk is not full.   /dev/xvda1       50G  6.4G   41G  14% /

Comment: Please suggest how do I track this issue.Let me know what should i do if again this problem raised.